# Find out if array contains arithmetic progression in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
var myarray = [1,2,3,4,7,9,12,13,14]
```

I need to group values like so:

```
var array_1 = 1,2,3,4
var array_2 = 7
var array_3 = 8
var array_4 = 12,13,14
```

I need to find a sequences with an arithmetic progression and seperate from other values.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `var array_3 = 9` ?

Comment: if the previous value is not this value plus one, then ??? :)

Comment: I'm not convinced there is a unique solution to this, as you have phrased it. You could also have something like `1,4,7`, and let the rest be single groups/groups of 2. Or `1,2,3`, `4,9,14`, then 7/9/12/13 all singles

Comment: @versim yes, sorry typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this solution

```
    function explode(myarray) 
    {  
        var multi = []; 
        var i = j = 0;
        for ( key in myarray ) 
        {
            if((myarray[key-1]) != (myarray[key]-1))
            {
                i++;
                j=0;
            }
            if(j==0)
                multi[i] = [];
            multi[i][j] = myarray[key];
            j++;
        }
        return multi;
    }
```

It returns a multidimentionnal array that you can use in your example like this

```
var myarray = [1,2,3,4,7,9,12,13,14];

var multi_array = explode(myarray);

var array_1 = multi_array[0];
var array_2 = multi_array[1];
var array_3 = multi_array[2];
var array_4 = multi_array[3];
```

**New update :**

You can also remove the `j` index and use `.push` to add new elements to your array

```
function explode(myarray) 
{  
    var multi = []; 
    var i = 0;
    for ( key in myarray ) 
    {
        if((myarray[key-1]) != (myarray[key]-1))
            i++;
        if(!multi[i])
            multi[i] = [];
        multi[i].push(myarray[key]);
    }
    return multi;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work, but displays a slightly different output than the one you expect.
In your example, I think 7 and 9 should be grouped (any sequence of two items is an arithmetic
progression after all). Or if they are not grouped, then 12 should not be grouped with 13 and
14 either, since 12-9 != 13-12

```
function split(arr) {
       if (arr.length < 2) {
          return;
       }
       var delta = undefined;
       var start = 0;
       for (var idx = 1; idx < arr.length; idx++) {           
           if (delta === undefined) {
               delta = arr[idx] - arr[idx - 1];
           }
           if (arr[idx] - arr[idx - 1] != delta) {
             alert("subarray " + arr.slice(start, idx));
             start = idx;
             delta = undefined;
          }  
       }
       alert("subarray from" + arr.slice(start, arr.length));
    }

split([1,2,3,4,7,9,12,13,14]);
```

Comment: Looks promising but doesn't work with this array:
[1,2,4,6,7,8,9,11,12]

Comment: As others have said, I think your definition of the problem is not complete enough. My algorithm returns: [1,2], [4,6], [7,8,9], [11,12], where each of these arrays is indeed an arithmetic progression, and the longest possible.

Comment: Reading the accepted solution, it seems you expect an arithmetic progression where the delta is 1. That's not the generate mathematical solution. My solution works when the delta can be different from 1 (for instance, the second array above is an arithmetic progression of 2, as in 4,6,8,10.

Comment: You are right, sorry I didn't explain my question enough. English is not my first language

Answer (score 1):

```
arrays = Array();
var c = 0;
array[c][] = myarray[0]);
for (var i = 1; i<myarray.length; i++) {
    if (myarray[i-1] +1 != myarray[i])
        c++;
    array[c][] = push(myarray[i]);
}
```

not sure the array syntax (might mix up languages here) is correct or whether I understand your problem fully.